# Adding specific options to cdktf command (terraform cdktf python )

Tags: python, terraform, terraform-cdk

I am trying to add specific options to the cdktf terraform commands with python :
Actually, I want to specify the environment that can contain: prod , dev , test when calling cdktf synth or deploy, so it will look like this: cdktf synth/deploy -environment "prod".

I was thinking of python argparse :

import argparse

class MyStack(TerraformStack):

```
def __init__(self, scope: Construct, id: str):
    super().__init__(scope, id)
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    # Add the product and stage options
    parser.add_argument('-environment', type=str, help='The environment name')
    # Parse the command-line arguments
    args = parser.parse_args()
    # and then use the environment when calling aws resource
```

and I don't understand why cdktf can't parse these options in my main.py to be honest it's
a lot of abstractions and a lack of documentation.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will work. You're trying to pass arguments to the cdktf program which may or may not pass those extra args to the underlying program.

Something that would work is passing extra args as environment variables i.e. `ENVIRONMENT="prod" cdktf synth/deploy` and modify your code to read these.

Another option is to use terraform variables and again pass them as environment variables as documented here: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cdktf/concepts/variables-and-outputs#passing-input-variables-to-cdktf